# Why the mat type is different?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I loaded a image to original_pre of size 160x60,following is the code

```
original_pre = cvLoadImage(input, 0);
int border = 5;
CvMat* original_mat = cvCreateMat(original_pre->height-2*border, original_pre->width-2*border, CV_8UC3);
original = cvCreateImage(cvSize(original_pre->width-2*border, original_pre->height-2*border), original_pre->depth, original_pre->nChannels);
cvGetSubRect(original_pre, original_mat, cvRect(border,border,original_pre->width-2*border,original_pre->height-2*border));

cvFloodFill(original_mat,cvPoint(0,0),cvScalarAll(0),cvScalarAll(1),cvScalarAll(1));
CvMat* original_open_mat = cvCreateMat(original_pre->height-2*border, original_pre->width-2*border, CV_8UC3);
CvMat* temp = cvCreateMat(original_pre->height-2*border, original_pre->width-2*border, CV_8UC3);
cout<<original_mat->width<<" "<<original_mat->height<<" "<<original_open_mat->width<<" "<<original_open_mat->height<<" "<<CV_MAT_TYPE(original_mat->type)<<" "<<CV_MAT_TYPE(original_open_mat->type)<<" "<<CV_8UC3<<endl;
cvMorphologyEx(original_mat,original_open_mat,temp,NULL,CV_MOP_OPEN);
```

after the floodfill operation the type of original_mat and original_open_mat is different.
The result printed is

```
150 50 150 50 0 16 16
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.size() == dst.size() && src.type() == dst.type()) in cvMorphologyEx, file /home/ataosky/software/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/morph.cpp, line 1353
```

the original_mat's type is 0 while the original_open_mat's type is 16.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I run your code with a simple image and it is working perfectly fine.. Here is the code and the result. I assume **original_pre** and **original** are of **IplImage*** type as they are not present in you block of code.

```
IplImage*   original_pre = cvLoadImage("G:\\test.png");
int border = 5;
    CvMat* original_mat = cvCreateMat(original_pre->height-2*border, original_pre->width-2*border, CV_8UC3);
IplImage* original = cvCreateImage(cvSize(original_pre->width-2*border, original_pre->height-2*border), original_pre->depth, original_pre->nChannels);
cvGetSubRect(original_pre, original_mat, cvRect(border,border,original_pre->width- 2*border,original_pre->height-2*border));

cvFloodFill(original_mat,cvPoint(50,55),cvScalarAll(255),cvScalarAll(0),cvScalarAll(0));
CvMat* original_open_mat = cvCreateMat(original_pre->height-2*border, original_pre->width-2*border, CV_8UC3);
CvMat* temp = cvCreateMat(original_pre->height-2*border, original_pre->width-2*border,  CV_8UC3);
cout<<original_mat->width<<" "<<original_mat->height<<" "<<original_open_mat->width<<" "<<original_open_mat->height<<" "<<CV_MAT_TYPE(original_mat->type)<<" "<<CV_MAT_TYPE(original_open_mat->type)<<" "<<CV_8UC3<<endl;
cvMorphologyEx(original_mat,original_open_mat,temp,NULL,CV_MOP_OPEN);
cvSaveImage("G:\\temp_.jpg",original_open_mat);
```

**Original Image**

[image: Original Image]

**Result**

[image: Result]